# Mapping entities "ignoring" intermediate table

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have in my database 3 tables with many-to-one relationships between them:

```
A *---1 B *---1 C
```

Now I have entities like:

```
class A {
   private B b;
   ...
}

class B {
   private C c;
   ...
}

class C {
   ...
}
```

Now my question is if it is possible to have Hibernate XML mapping to achieve this:

```
class A {
   private C c;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. But you may have a getter method:

```
public C getC() {
    return b.getC();
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok, guess I'll do it this way. Thanks for the idea :)